# Django Models Excel-Like relations

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I want to achieve a relationship between two fields in Django models. I understand that the desired view can only be achieved with additional views.py and forms.py. However, I need to choose the right models beforehand.

[Relations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBJge.png)

In the image provided, the relationship between the "A-ID" and "Important for" fields is illustrated. When an "A-ID" is marked as "YES" the "Important for" field should be dynamically split based on the number of "A-ID" entries labeled as "Yes."

Is a many-to-many field necessary here? Unfortunately, I haven't found a similar structure online.

My Code in models.py so far

```
class MyClass(models.Model):

    yes_no_choices = [
    ('YE', 'YES'),
    ('NO', 'NO'),
    ]
    A_ID = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    Information = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True) 
    Importance = models.CharField(
        max_length=2,
        choices=yes_no_choices,)

    B_ID = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    Information_2 = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True) 
    Important_for = ?
```

Answer (score 0):

A many-to-many field is the correct solution to your use case. I would suggest splitting up `A` and `B` into separate tables, then creating a m2m field on one of them. Either B mapping to many As or A mapping to many Bs. In either case, you can use the [related manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager), to get both sides of the m2m relation.

Answer (score 0):

When we have separate ID's we should be making separate models to correspond to these unique ID's. So your code should have a model to represent A, a model to represent B, and then a ManyToMany field on B pointing to A. This will allow each instance of B (given by it's unique ID) to have a relationship to any given series of ID's in A. We know it's a ManyToMany because each ID of A can be linked to multiple different ID's of B at once.

It should end up something like

```
class A(models.Model):
    information = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    importance = models.BooleanField(default=True)

class B(models.Model):
    information = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    important_for = models.ManyToManyField('A', blank=True)
```